# Count percent of records among similar records

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have table t:

```
ID    Type
----  ----
1     a
1     b
2     a
2     a
3     b
```

And table with names of IDs from first table - n:

```
ID    Name
----  ----
1     name1
2     name2
3     name3
```

I need make query in PL/SQL for count percentage of type occurrence among all types for same id (group by ID).

The result must be:

```
Name   a%   b%     row
---    ----  ---   ---
name1  50    50   1
name2  100   0    2
name3  0     100  3
```

I tried:

```
select 
    n.name,
    a.perc as "a%",
    b.perc as "b%",
    row_number() over (
        order by name asc
    ) mf_rownumber
from n n
left join
    (select 
        id,
        round(100 * (count(*) / sum(count(*)) over ()), 2) perc
    from t
    where (type = 'a')
    group by id) a
    on a.id = n.id
left join
    (select 
        id,
        round(100 * (count(*) / sum(count(*)) over ()), 2) perc
    from t
    where (type = 'b')
    group by id) b
    on b.id = n.id;
```

What I get, is percentage of every type from all rows:

```
Name    a%   b%     row
---     ----  ---   ---
name1   20    20   1
name2   40    0    2
name3   0     20   3
```

But I need count everything in borders of the same ID, not all rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it can be simplified a lot :
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6bb2a/20

```
 select 
    n.name,
    round(100 * (sum(case when type='a' then 1 else 0 end) / count(*)), 2) as "a%",
    round(100 * (sum(case when type='b' then 1 else 0 end) / count(*)), 2) as "b%",
    row_number() over (order by name asc ) mf_rownumber
from n 
left join t on t.id = n.id
group by n.name
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
select 
    n.name,
    n.id, 
    count(case when type='a' then 1 end)/count(*)*100 as "a%",
    count(case when type='b' then 1 end)/count(*)*100 as "b%" 
from n left join t on a.id=n.id 
group by n.id;
```